# OPENOCD Error codes: How do I fix this?

Tags: debugging

I have a chip I am trying to use JTAG communications with using openOCD. However, I get the following error:

```
openocd -f ocd.cfg 
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Warn : Adapter driver 'buspirate' did not declare which transports it allows; assuming legacy JTAG-only
Info : only one transport option; autoselect 'jtag'
srst_only separate srst_gates_jtag srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
Info : Buspirate Interface ready!
Info : This adapter doesn't support configurable speed
Warn : There are no enabled taps.  AUTO PROBING MIGHT NOT WORK!!
Info : TAP auto0.tap does not have IDCODE
Warn : AUTO auto0.tap - use "jtag newtap auto0 tap -irlen 2 -expected-id 0x00000000"
Error: auto0.tap: IR capture error; saw 0x0002 not 0x0001
Warn : Bypassing JTAG setup events due to errors
Warn : gdb services need one or more targets defined
```

I suspect this is due to a poor connection somewhere, but I don't know which lead to suspect. How should I go about debugging this issue?

To be clear I am asking this from the perspective of OpenOCD software, not my hardware: 
**Why does it expect 0x0001? Can I configure it to expect 0x0002?**

**Why is it giving up after these two errors?**

For the record I am using this config:

```
source [find interface/buspirate.cfg]


buspirate_vreg 0
buspirate_mode open-drain
buspirate_pullup 1

buspirate_port /dev/tty.usbserial-A90809RC
```

As my chip is not includes in the /boards directory, I could include a board from there using the source directive.

Comment: Did you try OpenOCD support channels?

Comment: You mean on IRC? or do they have a forum or something?

Comment: As was explained when you asked this on EESE, openocd can't do anything until you tell it what chip you are talking to. If you don't know what the chip is, you'll need to determine that by other means first.